# ajaxSubmit error case

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

Hy guys. i have this problem. i tried to solve but i can't.
It's about ajaxSubmit function.

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: 'url',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: 'false',
            beforeSend: function(){
                alert('before')
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert('success')
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
 });
```

Always access error case with:

```
Object {aborted: 0, responseText: "{"success":false,"error_message":"<p>The 

Title fie…:"The Introduction text field is required."}}</p>", responseXML: document, status: 0, statusText: "n/a"…}abort: function (status) {aborted: 0error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <getAllResponseHeaders: function () {}getResponseHeader: function (header){responseText: "{"success":false,"error_message":"<p>The Title field is required.&lt;\/p&gt;\n</p><p>The Introduction text field is required.&lt;\/p&gt;\n","error_fields":{"title":"The Title field is required.","intro_text":"The Introduction text field is required."}}</p>"responseXML: nullsetRequestHeader: function () {}status: 0statusText: "n/a"__proto__: Object
```

and controller response

```
{"success":false,"error_message":"<p>The Title field is required.<\/p>\n<p>The Introduction text field is required.<\/p>\n","error_fields":{"title":"The Title field is required.","intro_text":"The Introduction text field is required."}}
```

Comment: I guess you are missing to send necessary field and in background code it controls these fields. If these fields are missing then throws exception so the response code is not 200.

Comment: You have fields `Introduction, Title` with required attribute. It is not validating at your client's side though server throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
    type: "POST", // Enter Request type GET/POST
    url: 'action.php', // Enter your ajax file URL here,
    dataType: 'json', // If you are using dataType JSON then in php file use die( json_encode($resultArray) );
    cache: 'false',
    data: {_keyName: "abcd"}, // Put your values here
    beforeSend: function(){
        alert('before')
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

Tell me if anything else

Comment: Sateesh thx for your quick answer. I don't want to post data using ajax function. i use it just for handle controller json respond. The post works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code in server side , because you had no error in client side

Try this steps:

1- Print any clear thing for example:
echo "test "

2- If you have no error check your response data because,
I guess you missed comma or added html element in wrong way

Comment: This is $validation_result variable:
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 
    [error_fields] => Array
        (
            [title] => The Title field is required.
            [intro_text] => The Introduction text field is required.
        )

)
And this is echo line:
echo json_encode($validation_result);

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
    type: "POST", // Enter Request type GET/POST
    url: 'action.php', // Enter your ajax file URL here,
    dataType: 'json', // If you are using dataType JSON then in php file use die( json_encode($resultArray) );
    cache: 'false',
    data: {_keyName: "abcd"}, // Put your values here
    beforeSend: function(){
        alert('before')
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
 });
```